# What do the stereochemical labels D and − mean in tartaric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

> [image: D-tartaric acid]
>
> Why is the isomer of tartaric acid above labelled as ᴅ and (−)?
>
> 1. it rotates plane-polarized light clockwise
> 2. it rotates plane-polarized light anticlockwise
> 3. it is an equimolar mixture of the enantiomorphs
> 4. its configuration is related to that of ᴅ-glyceraldehyde

If I am not wrong, the ᴅ in ᴅ-glyceraldehyde refers to (+)-glyceraldehyde, and likewise ʟ-glyceraldehyde is (−)-glyceraldehyde. The (+) and (−) labels indicate that these isomers are dextrorotatory and levorotatory, respectively.

So in ᴅ-(−)-tartaric acid, what does the ᴅ mean, if not *dextro*, and what does the (−) mean, if not *levo* (the minus sign indicating anticlockwise rotation of plane-polarized light)? How can one molecule be both?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextrorotation_and_levorotation#Chirality_prefixes) has a useful section on this topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I remember, small *d* always means the same as (+), not small cap ᴅ. So, a dextrorotatory compound is prefixed with either (+) or *d* while a levorotatory compound is prefixed with either (−) or *l*.

Small caps ᴅ and ʟ prefixes have different meaning: if an enantiomer can in principle be synthesized from naturally occurring (+)-glyceraldehyde without affecting its configuration, it is considered the ᴅ-form. Otherwise, it is considered the the ʟ-form. And, say, the ᴅ-form of a molecule is not necessarily a dextrorotatory one.

So, the answers to your question are options 2 (the (−) sign indicates that it rotates plane-polarized light anticlockwise), *and* option 4 (the ᴅ label indicates that it is related to ᴅ-glyceraldehyde).

Answer (score 6):

*Dextrorotatory* and *levorotatory* are a set of two terms that designate the direction polarised light is rotated to by a specific compound. Chiral compounds can be identified as being chiral due to their optical activity only. The optical activity is a physically measurable parameter, determined in polarimeters and calculated to a specific optical activity by dividing by concentration and length of the cuvette. Rotation to the right is indicated by a $(+)$ sign, while rotation to the left is indicated by a $(-)$.

The names *dextro-* and *levorotatory* derive from the Latin words *dexter* *(right,* as in *right hand)* and *laevus* *(left,* as in *left hand).*

---

The D/L-nomenclature is entirely different from the above. While the prefixes D and L also derive from the same Latin words, they are used in a different way. They key to D/L-nomenclature is a [Fischer projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer_projection). If a chiral molecule is drawn in such a (linear) projection, and the group of the highest priority (typically the group with the highest oxidation state) is at the top, a compound is defined as L if the non-hydrogen atom on the lowest asymmetric carbon of the chain points to the *left.* Likewise, if it points to the *right,* a compound is termed D.

[image: D-Glyceraldehyde] [image: L-Tartaric acid] [image: D-Tartaric acid]
From left to right: D-Glyceraldehyde, L-tartaric acid, D-tartaric acid.

---

It is very important to know that **there is no connection between D/L and the direction of rotation of polarised light!** Likewise, one cannot deduce the direction of optical activity from knowing whether a compound is (*R*) or (*S*). D/L and (*R*)/(*S*) can be determined on paper or *via* crystal structures while $(+)/(-)$ can *only* be determined experimentally in a polarimeter or similar experiments.

That D-glyceraldehyde is dextrorotatory is a mere (but maybe lucky) coincidence.

---

Therefore, the correct answers to your given question are (2) (it rotates to the left; $(-)$) and (4) (it relates back to D-Glyceraldehyde).