# Confusion in D/L nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature, stereochemistry, isomers

[image]

With regard to carbohydrates, it is known that in a Fischer projection, if the $-OH$ group is on the right side of the lowest priority asymmetrical (chiral) carbon, then we name it as D and if it is on the left side we name is as L. But my question if in the left compound of the image, i.e. D-glyceraldehyde, why have we kept the $-CHO$ group on the top of the vertical line and the $-CH_{2}OH$ group on the bottom of the vertical line ( or alternatively just rotate the molecule by 180 degrees), because if I exchange both the groups at the vertical position with each other, and both the groups of the horizontal position with each other, then we get the same molecule, but now -OH is on the left so it will be L !? Where am i wrong, how do we know which groups will be on top and which on the bottom, in the Fischer projection. Need help.

Comment: The carbon with the highest oxidation state is kept at the top.

Comment: I think you should read https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3709/are-you-confused-by-confusing-question-titles-including-the-word-confusion?r=SearchResults&s=1|30.9232

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16914/what-do-the-stereochemical-labels-d-and-%e2%88%92-mean-in-tartaric-acid/59447#59447 ?